# Duplicate removal after spliting pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split

I want to send as keys values after splitting using the below code:

```py
for row in all_data2.itertuples():
    for ele in row.vertical_concat.split(" "):
        if 3 < len(ele) < 25:
            ele_new = str(ele) + str(i) + str(ele)
            print(ele_new)
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(send).send_keys(ele_new).perform()
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(send).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

I'm converting the values and send them as this : apple::apple(is the required format in this case).

Is there a way I can remove duplicate words since I may have values as:

```
apple::apple
apple::apple
```

And I want to send them once.

Thank you so much for any suggestion.

Comment: what do you mean with duplicate words ? your desidered output is ['apple::apple'] instead of  ['apple::apple' ,'apple::apple' ] ?

Comment: @BlackMath exactly, send one time only that value as key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can store every output of your loops inside a list (`already_printed` for example).
Using `set()` we can manage eventual duplicates inside that list.

Then, you can do something like this:

```
already_printed = set()
for row in all_data2.itertuples():
    for ele in row.vertical_concat.split(" "):
        if ele not in already_printed:
           if 3 < len(ele) < 25:
             ele_new = str(ele) + str(i) + str(ele)
             print(ele_new)
        else:
             already_printed.add(ele)
```

Comment: I think this will maintain order `pd.unique(my_list).tolist()`

Comment: @AnuragDabas Using "list comprehension" + enumerate() will also preserve order.

Comment: @BlackMath I need to maintain the two 'for' and iterate over rows. I tried with lists but then I will not be able to add them one under another when sending them as keys, its just blocks after the first value is sent. So the iteration needs to be done over rows and not for elements in list